# Layer-Backed view no longer punches hole in transparent NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview, quartz-core

I am trying to make a "hole" in an NSWindow using a CAShapeLayer or even just a CALayer.

When using regular NSViews or even layer-backed views, I can override drawRect: using code like this:

```
        [spotImage drawInRect:self.bounds fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeXOR fraction:1.0];
```

where spotImage is an NSImage with pure white content and some gradations, and the window has a black background with 0.5 alpha. The NSView subclass where this drawRect is defined has a clearColor background.

The end result is a grey window (It is a transparent window with a styleMask of NSBorderlessWindowMask as can be found in many samples.

If I turn the NSView into a layer-backed view, it calls the drawRect methods and works fine.

When I turn this into a layer-hosting view, and again use the same structure (NSWindow > contentView > CustomView) then, the drawInRect method just draws the image. It no longer punches a hole through it.

It is like the layer itself can no longer punch the hole when it is part of a layer-hosting hierarchy.

Here is some sample code:

The custom NSWindow subclass initializer:

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag {

self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

if (self) {

   [self setBackgroundColor: [NSColor lightGrayColor]]; //[NSColor clearColor]];

    [self setAlphaValue:0.5];

    [self setOpaque:NO];
    [self setHasShadow: NO];

    [self useOptimizedDrawing:YES];
    [self setIgnoresMouseEvents:YES];
}
return self;
```

}

the code in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
PPContentView *thisView = [[PPContentView alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectInset([self.window.contentView bounds], 50, 50)];

//[thisView setWantsLayer:YES]; enabling this makes things opaque again

[self.window.contentView addSubview:thisView];

thisView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor].CGColor;

//Create custom content
[thisView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

}

and my custom view's drawRect contains:

```
    [[NSImage imageNamed:@"spotFuzzy.png"] drawInRect:self.bounds fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeXOR fraction:1.0];
```